# Subfunctor of a sheaf which is not a sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

The following is proposition 1 from Maclane & Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, part II, section 1.

**Proposition 1.** If $F$ is a sheaf on $X$, then a subfunctor $S\subset F$ is a subsheaf if and only if, for every open set $U$ and every element $f\in FU$, and every open covering $U=\bigcup U_i$, one has $f\in SU$ if and only iff $f|_{U_i}\in SU_i$ for all $i$.

I really feel i'm missing the story here. Why, generally speaking, isn't the condition [$f\in SU$ if and only iff $f|_{U_i}\in SU_i$ for all $i$] enough for a general presheaf, not necessarily a subfunctor of a sheaf, $S$ to be a sheaf?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Proposition 1 says "S is a sheaf iff P holds" and you then ask "why isn't P enough for S to be a sheaf?"

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean for general $S$, not necessarily $S$ a subfunctor of a sheaf. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't know what that condition means if $S$ isn't a subfunctor of a sheaf; specifically, I don't know what the right-to-left part of the iff means.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "Why, generally speaking, isn't the condition [$f\in SU$ if and only iff $f|_{U_i}\in SU_i$ for all $i$] enough for a general presheaf - not necessarily a subfunctor of a sheaf - $S$ to be a sheaf?"

Comment: What do you think the right-to-left part of that condition means? "If $f |_{U_i} \in SU_i$ for all $i$, then $f \in SU$." What is $f$ here? In Proposition 1, $f \in FU$. But here there's nowhere for $f$ to live.